# Embed PDF on a webpage and prevent download

Tags: html, pdf

Is there a way to embed a PDF document on a webpage and at the same time disabling download? If possible I would prefer an html5/css3 solution. If no other way is possible I'd go with something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2017 Note: this feature has moved locations and the implementation has changed since it was originally answered.

---

Google Viewer offers a [solution](https://docs.google.com/viewer).

Use the iframe it generates for you.

Comment: It really isnt possible to save the document using iframe, but in the top right corner of the frame there is a full-screen mode button and in full-screen mode it is possible to print to PDF.

Comment: Above Method does NOT disable download functionality.

Comment: You can alter the code of that generated iframe using PHP (change the reference urls of js files from relative paths to absolute) and disable the print button.

Comment: The link provided in this answer doesn't work. Will remove down-vote if this is fixed.

Comment: @Luke Google removed the page in 2015. The viewer app is still available using `https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=<url_to_document>`, but now there’s a popup button to launch the full-feature viewer, including download and print, so not really a solution anymore.

Answer (score 15):

just add `#toolbar=0` to the url of the pdf

Comment: Very usefull and simple answer, i just tried it and worked! Thank you.

Comment: You still see the URL to the pdf in the sourcecode.

Comment: But... what if I want to allow printing? Is there an option that doesn't hide the whole toolbar?

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Yes there is:

```
<div id="pdf">
    <object width="100%" height="650" type="application/pdf" data="[ImageURLHere]#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="pdf_content" style="pointer-events: none;">
        <p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
    </object>
</div>
```

The `pointer-events: none` styling will also prevent users from right-clicking the PDF and downloading.

Comment: What if a user uses "view page source"? Than he can still get the URL right?

Comment: I tried it on my Angular 4 app and it just shows the base index.html page. I tried digging into the console tabs and couldn't find the asset anywhere.

Comment: This is not going to work. Also, adding the pointer-events: none; to the style will also disable scrolling for the pdf.

Comment: In 2023, using Chrome, scrolling works and the printing and downloading buttons were removed.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it is possible, you can adjust in your Google Drive option "Prevent viewers from downloading"
Then set PDF file public, so everyone can view PDF in Viewer, but none can download it.
I hope, that this will help for some.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is, it can't be done.  The only way to view a PDF document without any kind of conversion is via the adobe PDF plugin, and that invariably allows the document to be saved.  On top of that, it's trivial to use various tools to get the url of the PDF and download it from there.

If you want to avoid sending the actual PDF document, you could create a server-side script that converts the PDF document to a series of PNG or JPG images behind the scenes.  You can do this with [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) for example.

But then, the actual content of the document still reaches the user, only in a different format.  If this is not satisfactory for you, there are [various](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-ways-to-protect-images-from-being-stolen/) [techniques](http://labnol.blogspot.com.au/2007/08/prevent-visitors-from-downloading.html) you can use to prevent *most* users from saving the images, but these are easily circumvented by a sufficiently technically savvy user.

Comment: Can i at least remove control bar of a PDF plugin??? Soo at least ordinary users wont know how to download it. Oh and i would probbably had to prevent the right click also.

Comment: You can use any of available PDF rasterizer's available,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SlideShare](http://slideshare.net), you can set a read password, prevent users from downloading in the settings, and even create a secret link so only users with it can open it. I am sure there are ways to circumvent this, but at least it's not immediate.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the PDF.js and modify these 2 files: viewer.html and viewer.js, remove/modify the corresponding buttons/actions in order to disable downloading/printing, and you can furtherly disable right click menu items.