# Need to block right click on PDF Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have disabled the right click every where on my page but only on the pdf which I am generating dynamically I am unable to disable it.

Below is the HTML Part

```
<app-card *ngIf="show"> 
    <embed [src]="Url" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1000px" EnableContextMenu='0' >
</app-card>
```

Here is the TS Part I have also sanitized the URL.

```
this.busy = this.http1.post('http://192.168.1.183:8200/api/auditUser', data).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res == 'Record Not found') {
        swal('No Record Found', 'Please Try Again', 'warning');
        this.show = false;
      } else {
        this.pdfPath = res;
        this.toolbar = '#toolbar=0';
        this.pdfSrc = 'http://192.168.1.183/' + this.pdfPath + this.toolbar;
        this.Url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfSrc);
        this.show = true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: can you add your code in stackbiltiz.com

Comment: Try adding oncontextmenu="return false;" in your embed html element or the parent of it.

Comment: Tried not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let try this once,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onmousedown = disableRightclick;
var message = "Right click not allowed !!";
function disableRightclick(evt){
    if(evt.button == 2){
        alert(message);
        return false;    
    }
}
</script>
```

Refered link
https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/embed-pdf-disable-right-click-using-javascript/&hl=en-IN

Second way

```
<html>
<body oncontextmenu= "return false;">
Right Click not allowed on this page
</body>
</html>
```

Refered link

https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/disable-right-click-on-ltembed-gt-pdf-file-in-sharepoint&hl=en-IN

Finally possible solution for you

[Embed PDF on a webpage and prevent download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129733/embed-pdf-on-a-webpage-and-prevent-download)

These are just for an suggestion.

Comment: OK brother let me try & get back to you

Comment: didnt worked I have disabled the whole page, but i want to disable on the pfd

Answer (score 1):

You can use Host property to disable the app-card component

> The host property is used to bind the events to all the attributes to
>   that particular class component

Inside your app-card decorator you need to define host property

```
selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
 host: {
    '(contextmenu)': 'disableClick($event)'
  }
```

Then you need to define the method inside your app-card class

```
private disableClick(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Check this example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/contextmenu-clickoutside

Comment: No result but appreciate your efforts

Comment: It is disabling right click on text I need to disable on pdf